# EventTrigger и PreviewMouseMove

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Как правильно установить `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseMove">,` чтобы ListBoxItem менял цвет?

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Category}" Background="#171717">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListBoxItem>
                            <ListBoxItem.Content>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image></Image>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ListBoxItem.Content>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSteelBlue"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseMove">
                                <!--<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/> как реализовать такие сеттеры?
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>-->
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseMove">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ListBoxItem.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ListBoxItem.BorderThickness)">
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2"/>
            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

При изменении таким же образом *Foreground* - ошибки, так что будьте осторожны)